# Cordova App with Visual Studio 2003 - WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I am trying to develop some Apps with Cordova and Visual Studio.

I used Intel XDK, and now planning to develop with VS. However, unlike XDK, there is no option for WYSIWYG Editor or design editor.

Can anyone suggest me a good GUI editor integration or any plugin to achieve this task?

Please help.

Comment: Sorry to say this mate, but this question is more than an year old. However, I am happy you gave me your comments on it. :)